# Why doesn't help(SRE_Class) show anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, documentation

I can do,

```
import re
help( re.compile('') )
```

And, at the top, it says

```
class SRE_Pattern(builtins.object)
```

But if I do `help SRE_Pattern`, I see nothing,

> ```
> NameError: name 'SRE_Pattern' is not defined
> ```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

`SRE_Pattern` is actually implemented as part `_sre` ([S-expression RegExes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression) are called "SREs") a C-extension that handles most of the functionality of the `re` module. The docs you're reading when you do `help(re.compile(''))` are implemented in C with `PyDoc_STRVAR`. This is why you won't find a direct reference to it.

You can, however, peruse the [`_sre.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_sre.c#l2700) source code, it is defined there.